# Spring boot does not start when secondary datasource database connection unavailable

Tags: java, spring

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.DataSourcePublicMetrics.initialize(DataSourcePublicMetrics.java:64) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

I disabled the metrics too but no luck

```
endpoints.enabled=false
endpoints.autoconfig.enabled=false
endpoints.metrics.enabled=false
```

The `DataSourcePublicMetrics` bean always gets created, even when the metrics are disabled. This causes a `NullPointerException` when the database connection is unavailable, causing spring boot not to start.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Hikari datasource and it fails to construct data source object when database is unavailable. Hence NPE from DataSourcePublicMetrics bean. I am able to  circumvent the issue creating a Hikari data source that is lazy initialized with database config even when database is unavailable for later use when database becomes available. Not sure why HikariDataSource does not have a constructor for lazy init. It does have a default constructor but database config can't be set using any setter method. This is useful for applications where database is not always necessary to start them up.

```
public class LazyConnectionDataSource extends HikariDataSource {
    public LazyConnectionDataSource(HikariConfig config) {
        config.validate();
        config.copyState(this);
    }
}
```